# How to use transform:translate3d without breaking position:fixed?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout that I've found on another website that has a fixed header and two push menus, one on either side. After using inspect element in chrome, I can see that the website uses `transform:translate3d` to allow its menus to move left and right, but I can't work out how the developers have made the `body` of the site to move with them. A quick look has shown me that `transform:translate3d` doesn't seem to have been used on the `body` element, but I'm pretty sure that something is happening to that part of the code in order to move the main content around, as it is given an additional class when the menu buttons are clicked.

The site is: https://www.etq-amsterdam.com/

I have come up with a layout in a jsfiddle in which the buttons open the menus exactly the same as the site above, however the `body` of the site remains stationary.

**EXAMPLE 1:** https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/9/

I have also come up with a second jsfiddle using `transform:translate3d` on the `body` element, but this one breaks the fixed postioning on both the header and the push menus when the menus are opened.

**EXAMPLE 2:** https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/8/

Here is the code from **EXAMPLE 1:** which I think is closest to the code used om the website I provided above. Does anyone know how they have managed to get the body to move with the menus without breaking the fixed positioning on certain elements?

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
    <span id="button-one"></span>
    <span id="button-two"></span>
    <div class="push-menu-one"></div>
    <div class="push-menu-two"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>

<div class="content">

</div>

<footer class="footer">
Footer
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.footer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#button-one {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#button-two {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.push-menu-one {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 295px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: wheat;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(-295px, 0px, 0px)
}
.push-menu-two {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    width: 295px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: darkred;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(295px, 0px, 0px)
}
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s, width 0s ease 1s, height 0s ease 1s;
}
.overlay.open-right,
.overlay.open-left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.push-menu-one.open-left {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
}
.push-menu-two.open-right {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#button-one').click(function() {
        $('body, .overlay, .push-menu-one').toggleClass('open-left');

    });

    $('#button-two').click(function() {
        $('body, .overlay, .push-menu-two').toggleClass('open-right');

    });

    $('.overlay').click(function() {
        $('body, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-left');

        $('body, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-right');

    });

});
```

Comment: They aren't translating the `body`, they are translating `body .transform-container`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Quantastical.  Ok, so a child of the `body` – could you elaborate a bit for me? I'm a bit of a novice and I'm only used to moving things with `toggleClass` and I can't see any evidence here of them having done this. It also looks like they've used a different method than `transform:translate3d`, which might explain how they've done it without breaking the fixed positioning like I did in my second example above?

Comment: If you inspect the element with class `.transform-container` inside of `main#home` using your browser's Dev Tools, you will see the styles that are applied to it. You can also see that when the menu is open, they are toggling a class `.menu-open` on the body, which applies additional styles (the `transform` styles) to the `.transform-container` node. If you aren't familiar with DevTools (Press F12 in Chrome) and inspecting the code, then I would highly recommend getting acquainted with it as it is one of the most powerful tools in understanding how the browser is rendering things.

Comment: It is my understanding that they *are* using `translate3d` on the `.transform-container` as well.

Comment: You can't. Avoid `transform`

Comment: What I don't understand is how `.transform-container` is able to move the content in the `body` to the left and right, when it doesn't contain all of its child divs – i.e it doesn't contain the header and footer, and yet they all move in the same way that it does as if they were its child elements.

Comment: @Jack1991 If you look at the DevTools you will notice that transform rule is applied to the following selector: `body.menu-open #navBar.top, body.menu-open .transform-container` which includes both the `.transform-container` and the `#navBar.top` whenever the `body` has `.menu-open` applied to it. I see nothing about a footer that you speak of.